# google calendar events list in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, google-calendar-api

is there any module in Drupal 7 to integrate **google calendar** events.

need to display google events into D7 calendar.

Answer (score 4):

Let me start here a list of drupal modules working with google calendars. There are many, different, and some unfinished work.

[name+link],[7.x version or status],[some details]

- [fullcalendar](https://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar), 7.x-2.0, integration with google calendar is easy and limited (add a fullcalendar google calendar import field to the view);
- [gcal](https://drupal.org/project/gcal), 7.x-1.0-rc1, an implementation on google calendar API, I never tried it. The doc says it can: 1) Create, update, delete, get secondary Calendars; 2) Fetch single Calendar setting and list of settings; 3) Fetch Color settings; 4) Create, update, delete, get, move Events; 5) Create, delete, get Acl; 6) Create, update, delete, get CalendarList; 7) FreeBusy checking with events, quickAdd for events Current release includes. Not yet accomplished: 8) Import events and other features.
- [gcal_events](https://drupal.org/project/gcal_events), 7.x-1.x-dev, I never tried it. It display a block of upcoming events from a google calendar xml feed.
- [date_ical](https://drupal.org/project/date_ical), 7.x-2.13, I never tried it (yet, but I chose this solution). iCalendar is a standard internet calendar format (google calendar can export ical too). date_ical provides ical support in Drupal, provides a plugin for Views to enable exporting your site's calendar as an iCal feed, and a plugin for Feeds to enable importing external iCal feeds into your site's calendar.
- [agenda](https://drupal.org/project/agenda), 7.x-1.4, I never tried it. Display a list of upcoming events from Google Calendar as a block.
- [event_GCalendar](https://drupal.org/project/event_GCalendar), not finished, Google Calendar API.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Use the Google calendar field in [FullCalendar](http://dgo.to/fullcalendar) (http://dgo.to/fullcalendar).

FullCalendar is the Drupal module for the Full Calendar jQuery plug-in.

Drop in your Google calendar XML feed and you're good to go.